# How come the 3rd label and the button is not showing up in the UI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I'm learning Xamarin.Forms and the MVVM pattern, which includes data binding. I don't understand why after the 2nd label, nothing else shows up, but the breakpoint is hit for Str_Winner and the content of that string is as I expect the value to be.

Page_History.xaml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TicTacToe.ViewModel"
             x:Class="TicTacToe.View.Page_History">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local1:VM_GameInfo x:Key="VM_GameInfo"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{StaticResource VM_GameInfo}">

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GameHistory}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Str_Title}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding SaveDateTime}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Str_Winner}" />
                                <Button Text="Something"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

My code is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w1TL0am6VeS2dLgsesiQT_S2h0L7Lo1H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Need access to download your code sample.

Comment: Please add the relevant code here. External links may become inaccessible or the code there might change, making this question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `RowHeight="150"` or set `HasUnevenRows="True"` to the listView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GameHistory}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Str_Title}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding SaveDateTime}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Str_Winner}" />
                        <Button Text="Something"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you. HasUnevenRows="True" did it. As someone who's learning this, what recommendations do you have for me so that I can find answers to UI problems like this by myself? I don't know where to start looking because there are so many settings/properties that I don't know about yet.

Comment: I would recommend you to follow the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/) and there also examples code there. Feel free to ask here if you have any problem:).

Comment: Can you please accept this answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).